# Setting material in static class other than null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a static class I have a static variable that has a material set to null, this is then rewritten to other values through another piece of code. The only problem with this is when the game starts the ball has no material, it is just a 2d pink circle. I've tried multiple ways of setting the Ball material to something other than null but none work.

Here is the code i have in the static:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

static class ballmaterial 
{
    public static Material BallMaterial = null;
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Ise there any reasons for why it is static?

Comment: yes, i have to access it from another file to change its value.

Comment: @McGlovin So, just to clarify, initializing to something other than `null` results in the same `2d pink circle` or does not show anything?

Comment: Hard to say. Debug your code and you will find out if there is any code that sats the `BallMaterial` to null by mistake.

Comment: The null results in a pink 2d circle as there is no material set to the ball, but i do not know how to set a material to it as it is a static i cant set a material to it through the unity editor.

Comment: `I've tried multiple ways of setting the Ball material to something other than null but none work.` Can you detail those?

Comment: well at first i tried:  public static Material BallMaterial = color.white; which it said could not convert from material to colour. I then tried declaring ball material in the other piece of code to start with as white, which worked but then when changing scenes would revert back to white instead of keeping the colour it changed too.

Answer (score 1):

you could avoid using the static keyword (sucking the life out of your code) by using the singleton pattern this way :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

class ballmaterial 
{
    private static ballmaterial instance;
    private ballmaterial() {}

    public static ballmaterial Instance {
       get {
           if (instance == null) {
               instance = new ballmaterial();
           }
           return instance;
       }
    }

    public Material BallMaterial = null;
}
```

Then you should be able to set BallMaterial from anywhere in your code that way :

```
//in your gameobject component
public Material targetMaterial //the material you want to set it to (visible in inspector)
ballmaterial.Instance.BallMaterial = targetMaterial;
```

To keep modifications between scenes you should use the DontDestroyOnLoad function :

```
//in your gameobject component
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you, i will try it out later and will check you off as the correct answer if it works :)

Comment: The method of using dont destroy on load does not work properly as when loading a new scene it created a duplicate ( i understand why) but if in that scene i destroy the instance of the ball so it doesn't duplicate the ball that didnt get destroyed has none of the references to gameobjects in that scene, even if i make them prefabs they still dont work. it also duplicates when returning to the scene where the ball is first made.